# problems with a simple realtime joint controller in Gazebo

Tags: ros, microcontroller, gazebo, pr2-controller-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to follow along with the [Writing a realtime joint controller](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_mechanism/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20realtime%20joint%20controller) tutorial.  I've got the class all set up, and I believe I've got it installed correctly using the plugin lib, as I can see the controller when I do

```
rosrun pr2_controller_manager pr2_controller_manager list
```

and I can see that the plugin is running OK.  The problem is that even when I set the joint_state_->commanded_effort_ to a fixed value, I don't see any change in the joints of my simulation in gazebo.  However, when I do a rostopic echo of the /mechanism_statistics, I can see that the commanded effort is non-zero and that the limits haven't been violated:

```
name: p_one_joint_4
timestamp: 
  secs: 54
  nsecs: 5000000
position: 0.0
velocity: 0.0
measured_effort: 0.0
commanded_effort: -100.0
is_calibrated: True
violated_limits: False
odometer: 0.0
min_position: 0.0
max_position: 0.0
max_abs_velocity: 0.0
max_abs_effort: 0.0
```

Also, it is interesting that when I go into gazebo and tinker with the joints manually by using the little hand tool and making the joints move, I don't see anything when I add a printf into the controller to print the joint position (it stays 0).  I know that putting a printf in the controller is a bad idea for real-time behavior...  Any hints on why I can't get the joint to move with my simple controller would be appreciated.  Also in my joint definition in my URDF file I do not have a limit or safety_controller tag currently in it (they're below but commented out):

```
    <joint name="${parent}_${suffix}_joint_4" type="continuous">
        <origin xyz="${link_4_len} 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
        <!-- <limit effort="10" velocity="10" /> -->
        <!-- <safety_controller soft_lower_limit="-1.5" soft_upper_limit="1.5" k_position="1" k_velocity="1"/> -\-> -->
        <joint_properties damping="0.0" friction="0.0" />
        <parent link="${parent}_${suffix}_link_4" />
        <child link="${parent}_${suffix}_link_5" />
    </joint>
```

I have also verified that the links look OK in the simulation as well as in rviz, and the TF tree looks like it's being published.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10372/problems-with-a-simple-realtime-joint-controller-in-gazebo/) by [andrew-unit](https://answers.ros.org/users/407/andrew-unit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 283 on 2011-10-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) on 2011-11-15**:
Puting printfs in the realtime loop won't crash it, though it will diminish its performances you can try it. Have you been through this tutorial : http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_mechanism/Tutorials/Running%20a%20controller%20in%20simulation ?

**Comment by [andrew-unit](https://answers.ros.org/users/407/andrew-unit/) on 2011-10-26**:
Hmm.  Another observation is that when I fire up the simulation and grab the robot with the hand tool to get it to move the joints, and I try to do a rostopic echo of /joint_states, I see all the joints in my urdf file, but the positions, velocities, and effort are all zero.  Also in rviz it looks like the joints aren't moving at all.

**Comment by [sglaser](https://answers.ros.org/users/46/sglaser/) on 2012-02-14**:
Is this joint connected to any actuators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you have [gazebo_ros_controller_manager](http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_gazebo_plugins) or  an equivalent gazebo plugin in your simulated robot XML?

```
<gazebo>
  <controller:gazebo_ros_controller_manager name="gazebo_ros_controller_manager" plugin="libgazebo_ros_controller_manager.so">
    <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
    <updateRate>1000.0</updateRate>
  </controller:gazebo_ros_controller_manager>
</gazebo>
```

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2